# Deriving archimidean spiral from euler formula

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Starting from

$$(r(\theta)+d)e^{i \theta}=r(\theta +2\pi)e^{i(\theta + 2\pi)}, \theta\in\mathbb{R}^+$$

it is easy to show that $$r(\theta)+d=r(\theta + 2\pi)$$

Starting from there, I was able to prove that $r(\theta)$ has the form $c \theta^x$ taking into account that $\lim_{\theta \to 0}r(\theta)=0$ and $\lim_{\theta \to\infty}r(\theta)=\infty$ and $r(a) < r(b)$ where $a<b$. I also proved that $c = d$, but as the value of $x$, I got this non-correct result:

$$x=\dfrac{\ln\theta}{\ln\left(\dfrac{(\theta+1)(\theta+2\pi)}{\theta}\right)}$$

where it should have been $x=1$.

**EDIT:**

Having $r(0)=0$:

$$r(\theta)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(r(\theta+2\pi n)-nd)$$
$$r(\theta)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(r(\theta+2\pi n))-\lim_{n\to \infty}(nd)=\infty - \infty$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(r(\theta+2\pi n))=\lim_{n\to \infty}(nd)\to r(\infty)=\infty$$

$r(\theta)$ cannot have an indeterminate value, so one of those 2 limits is a fraction, not the $nd$ one, the $r(\theta + 2\pi n)$ one. Let $\phi = \theta +2\pi n$, now $r(\phi)=\dfrac{a(\phi)}{b(\phi)}$ but having $h(x)=n\dfrac{a(x)}{b(x)}$, we could rewrite $r(\phi)=\dfrac{h(\phi)}{n}$. Now $n$ is a constant.

$$r(0) = 0 \rightarrow h(0)=0, n \neq 0$$
$$r(\infty) = \infty \rightarrow h(\infty)=\infty, n \neq 0$$

So $h(\theta)$ has to pass from $(0,0)$ to $(\infty,\infty)$, and that's the form $c\theta^x$.

---

Now we are getting a little bit closer, now $r(\theta)=\dfrac{c\theta^x}{n}$, having $k=\frac{c}{n}$ so $r(\theta)=k\theta^x$.

Comment: How did you derive that it has the form $c\theta^x$? Supposing $r(\theta)=c\theta^x$, you could use the binomial expansion to expand $r(\theta+2\pi)=c(\theta+2\pi)^x=c(\theta^x+x\theta^{x-1}2\pi+\ldots)=r(\theta)+d$, if $x=1$ all higher terms vanish and $d=2\pi c$? [Generalised-binomial-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem) Although this wouldn't say why $x$ can't be anything other than $1$.

Comment: "...I was able to prove $r(\theta)$ has the form $c\theta^{x}$...": 1. What is $x$? 2. Why did you not deduce $r(\theta) = \frac{d}{2\pi}\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Correct solution

Seeing how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral) tells us that $r(\theta)=a+b\theta$ for suitably chosen $a,b$ (in your case for $a=0,b=\frac{d}{2\pi}$), I'd say $r(\theta)=c\,\theta^x$ is already a bit strange, and with $c=d$ as you claim it'd definitely wrong. Finding $x$ from this is futile.

To confirm that $r(\theta)=\frac{d}{2\pi}\theta$ does indeed satisfy your requirements:

$$r(0)=\frac{d}{2\pi}\cdot0=0\\
r(\theta)+d=
\frac{d}{2\pi}\theta+d=
\frac{d}{2\pi}\theta+\frac{d}{2\pi}2\pi=
\frac{d}{2\pi}(\theta+2\pi)=
r(\theta+2\pi)$$

### Your derivation

I find it extremely hard to follow your argument. Several steps appear without sufficient justification (like “$r(θ)$ cannot have an indeterminate value, so one of those 2 limits is a fraction”), while other steps have no obvious goal that I can see. I'm also worried that you seem to derive quite a lot of information from the fact that $\lim_{\theta\to\infty}r(\theta)=\infty$ which in fact does not convey much information about the finite behavior of the function. There are *many* strictly increasing functions which diverge, so concluding any specific form from this seems unwarranted.

### Constraints

Actually, knowing $r(0)=0$, $a<b\implies r(a)<r(b)$ and $r(\theta+2\pi)=r(\theta)+d$ is not enough to define the Archimedean spiral. You could pick *any* strictly monotonic function in the open interval $(0,2\pi)$ as long as its range is contained in $(0,d)$. Then the value of $r(\theta)$ would be defined as

$$r(\theta)=r\left(\theta-\left\lfloor\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\right\rfloor2\pi\right)+\left\lfloor\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\right\rfloor d$$

Example:

$$r(\theta)=\left(\frac{t}{2\pi}-\left\lfloor\frac{t}{2\pi}\right\rfloor\right)^4+\left\lfloor\frac{t}{2\pi}\right\rfloor$$

is a spiral satisfying your conditions with $d=1$. It's even continuous (which was not one of your requirements), but it's still not Archimedean:

[image: Figure of counterexample]